# How can i Auto Use Next CSS in Excel Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

On the Sofascore.com site, I will automatically take the link in cell A1 at https://www.sofascore.com/tr/football/2022-11-16 or similar, and run it in the for next loop and print some information of the matches on my table. In order to print the information, I first have to click on each match one by one. I also do this with CSS.Click. But since I'm going to do this over and over, I definitely need a loop. CSS links are very similar to each other, only 1 number changes for each match. The first thing that comes to my mind is a next loop for CSSs that automatically picks up the next CSS code, but I don't have enough knowledge. I want to consult experts, thanks in advance.
I am open to all suggestions.

```
 Sub sofascore()
 Dim x As New Selenium.ChromeDriver, i, sonsat As Integer
 x.SetProfile "C:\Users\Oğuzhan\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
 x.AddArgument ("user-data-dir=C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\System Profile")
 x.Start "chrome", "https://www.sofascore.com/"
 x.Window.Maximize
 Set ks = New Selenium.Keys
 sonsat = Sheets("veri").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
 For i = 2 To sonsat
 On Error Resume Next
 x.Get Range("A" & i).Value
 'CLICK THE SHOW ALL MATCHES ON THE SITE.
 x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-
hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-                hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.tYcjv.sc-cabffeca-2.loALSf > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.bdzsxu.hryjgv > button > div > span").Click
x.SendKeys ks.Home
x.Wait 200 
'CLICK ON MATCH 1 ON THE LIST
x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.tYcjv.sc-cabffeca-2.loALSf > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > a > div > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-9199a964-1.kusmLq").Click
x.Wait 1500
'THE FOLLOWING CODES PRINT THE MATCH DATA INTO THE COLUMNS.
codes..
..
'THIS IS IMPORTANT NOW. FOR MATCH 2, THE LOOP STARTS AGAIN AND WITH THE EXACT SAME CODES. HERE I HAVE TO MANUALLY WRITE THE 2nd CSS CODE :(
x.FindElementByCss("#__next > div > main > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-cabffeca-0.QpfGa > div.sc-hLBbgP.sc-eDvSVe.gjJmZQ.fEHohf.sc-cabffeca-1.iITCqu > div.sc-hLBbgP.tYcjv.sc-cabffeca-2.loALSf > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > a > div > div > div.sc-hLBbgP.dRtNhU.sc-9199a964-1.kusmLq").Click
x.Wait 1500
'Same codes upper
....
...
...
Next
End Sub
```

I've tried many ways but probably nonsense. Expert comments will enlighten me.

Comment: I tried my best to fix up your code formatting, but I am not sure if I got it right. Please [edit] your question so that the code is what you want. Also a good idea to have a browse through the [tour] and [ask] so you can enhance your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new here , sorry for mistake.